# Regarding orderer container

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, state-channels, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to setup multi channel network, every thing was working fine except my  Orderer was getting  exited immediately. As there is no Orderer I could not  proceed further. My setup consists of 3 ORGs and 1 peer for each ORG. So there should be 5 docker container processes including Orderer and cli where as when I was checking with docler ps command there were only 4 containers, docker ps -a was showing orderer Exited. Then I removed 3rd ORG from the setup and this issue got fixed. But now when I am trying other steps like creating channels, updating anchors, joining the channel etc. in between the cli is getting exited (but not immediately like orderer).  I thought this could be RAM issue and so I removed the 3rd ORG. Just wanted to confirm is this issue related to memory (RAM)? I am setting up this on ubuntu VM with 8 GB  total RAM. [this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXw8D.jpg)
[image]

Comment: This is off-topic I'm afraid, as per https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/are-questions-about-hyperledger-fabric-on-topic